# json.loads() in python behaving weird

Tags: python, json

I am writing a simple analytic server in python using bottle.

To test it I want to pass a json through the POST method however I have encountered an error and I do not know what is causing it - I am a beginner. The events are as follows:

First of all, this is my code to read the data from the json:

```
code = request.body.read()
data = json.loads(code)
print data
```

the expected result is to see a dictionary printed in the terminal.

This works perfectly fine with this json:

```
{
    "category" : "Videos",
    "action" : "play"
}
```

but the following one throws a `ValueError`:

```
{
    “url” : “www.google.com”,
    “session” : “1234hbnshgrjgcjbhrkfm9834”,
    “agent” : “firefox”,
    “os” : “Windows”,
    “referer” : "null"
}
```

Comment: That's because that's not valid JSON; try it in a online [JSON linter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and you'll notice that those quotes are not being accepted.

Comment: Just StackOverflow's syntax highlighter can see those aren't the right quotes ;-)

Comment: Because it is `“JSON”`, not JSON

Answer (score 7):

`json.loads()` assumes straight quotes (`""`) and not typographical (`“”`).